# Create Control with the name from the value of string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to create a new Control Object with the name being a value of a string. The reason being that the i need to pass it as the div for a location. Looking at the example below i want to change divName to the value of nameofDiv string. This div name already exists in the aspx page through a databind. So its not creating a div through code behind but strictly just using the name.

```
 string nameofDiv = "Divone";
 Button button = new Button();
 Control divName = new Control();
 divName.Controls.Add(button);
```

Comment: what name are you talking about? the variable *identifier*?

Comment: Why not using `.Name` property? `divName.Name = nameOfDiv`

Comment: Yes, why not using .Name property. It is settable for Control object. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi I am referring to the variable identifier. It seems that the .Name property is only available for windowsforms and not Web.UI.Page for asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope, this work for you,

```
string divOtherName = "divOne";
HtmlGenericControl divName = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divName .Attributes.Add("name", divOtherName);
divName .Attributes.Add("id", divOtherName);
```

Comment: Hi Sanjay Please read comment above it seems the .Name property is for winforms and not web.Ui.Page for asp.net

Comment: please see above, i've corrected as per Web.UI.Page.

Comment: Hi Sanjay, sorry i have updated the question. The div already exists in the aspx page but has be databound from the code behind already. I then want to use that name to add button. thanks